# Top or bottom margin between columns on smaller resolution

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

For a pattern like:

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-4">
      A
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
      B
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
      C
  </div>

</div>
```

The output on desktops is

```
+---+---+---+
| A | B | c |
+---+---+---+
```

When I resize the browser window to emulate a tab/phone, the output changes to

```
+---+
| A |
+---+
| B |
+---+
| C |
+---+
```

The expected output is

```
+---+
| A |
+---+
+---+
| B |
+---+
+---+
| C |
+---+
```

i.e., either a top or bottom margin. At the moment, I'm using a `clear:both` div with a height of `10px` between each cols to make that happen.

```
<div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-4">
          A
      </div>

      <div class="clear"></div> <!-- want to avoid using this -->

      <div class="col-md-4">
          B
      </div>

      <div class="clear"></div> <!-- want to avoid using this -->

      <div class="col-md-4">
          C
      </div>

</div>
```

Although this does the job, I was wondering if there was a more effective way of achieving it?

Comment: just add margin-bottom:20px to your inner divs

Comment: What is the problem with adding a bottom margin in JS with the width condition ? sthg like `if (myScreenWidth < 2*myDivWidth) myDiv.css('margin-bottom','10px');` (this is in jQuery but it is easy to do it in pure Js).

Comment: @user3657431 So there is no way that this can be done using bootstrap's classes alone?

Comment: @BastienSander Really want to avoid using more js code if something can be done through CSS alone

Comment: Why do you want to use bootstrap and no pure CSS ?

Comment: @BastienSander No particular reason..was hoping bootstrap has a fix for it within its framework for this. If that is the best possible option, then I guess I'll have to follow that only

Comment: @asprin you can add more bootstrap classes (depends on what dimension you need to change layout) - for example col-xs-12 and add margin-bottom for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <div class="row wrapper">

    <div class="col-md-4">
      Col A
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div> <!-- want to avoid using this -->

    <div class="col-md-4">
      Col B
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div> <!-- want to avoid using this -->

    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>

 </div> <!-- parent container -->
```

**CSS**
     /* use a media query to apply the CSS & edit your own break point */

```
 @media screen and (max-width:767px){ 

  .wrapper .col-md-4{
     margin-top:20px; /* use whatever gap u need */
   }

   .wrapper > *:first-child{  /* targeting the first child to remove top margin */
       margin-top:0;
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**HTML**

> ```
>   <div class="col-md-4 mbottom">
>       Col A
>   </div>
>
>
>   <div class="col-md-4 mbottom">
>       Col B
>   </div>
>
>
>   <div class="col-md-4 mbottom">
>   </div>
> ```

**CSS**

```
.mbottom{
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px; /* The size of the gap you want */
}
```

Comment: So using a custom class is the best option available? Doesn't bootstrap have some sort of trick to do so on its own?

Comment: Is what i use...i don´t think there is a way in bootstrap api

Comment: But this will also add the margin when the page is viewed on the desktop. So I guess I'll also have to add media queries to make sure that doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Uss **CSS Media Queries** as follows:

```
@media (max-width: 640px) {
    .col-md-4{margin-bottom:10px;}
}
```

Using above code will give `margin-bottom` of `10px` to `.col-md-4` divs when screen width is below `640px`.

Answer (score 0):

Without the use of media queries you could simply create a specific class and add margin-bottom instead of margin-top. That of course if you don't mind the margin underneath on desktop, but I presume you'll have some gap between the columns and the rest of the content anyway.